# Error: "Illegal characters found in URL" - Code: 3

Tags: php, curl

I want to get info from an api and the code is like:

```
<?php
  $curl = curl_init();
  $authorization = "Authorization: Token token='xxxxxx'";
  $header = curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authorization));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://customr.heliumdev.com/api/v1/customers/xxxx");
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  if(!curl_exec($curl)){
      print_r('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' .curl_errno($curl)."<br>");
  }
  curl_close($curl);
  print_r(json_decode($result));
?>
```

and I got the error like `Error: "Illegal characters found in URL" - Code: 3`

the origin curl should be `curl https://customr.heliumdev.com/api/v1/customers/xxxx --header "Authorization: Token token="xxx""`, any idear about the illegal characters?

Comment: In `xxxx` there are no illegal characters, but in the real string you provide to api - they __can__ be

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

Comment: @u_mulder Hi, I just tried `xxxx`, it still had errors

Comment: @DaleWilson Hi, it seems my url only have `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`.`, i cant find which part goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the problem.

However, I suggest you avoid the unnecessary double-execution of curl_exec and use the $result instead...

```
...
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if (!$result) {
   ...
}
```